# makefile variable pass

Tags: c++, makefile

I have written a makefile for my source code , and depends on the makfile input variable I include some dependable source files .

```
 ifeq($(var),mod1)
 src + = mod1.cpp 
 else ifeq ($(var),mod2)
 src + = mod2.cpp 
 else ifeq ($(var),mod3)
 src + = mod3.cpp 
 endif
```

I compile this using $make var=mod1 . this works fine when I want to include a single  variable . But I need to provide the option to include any combination of variable among mod1,mod2,mod3 .

Like $make mod1 mod2  or make mod3 mod1   etc

How to provide these kind of combination in the  make file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass multiple argument to make file as you want.

### Make File (makefile)

```
all:
     echo $(NAME)
     echo $(AGE)
     echo $(TEL)
```

### In console

```
make NAME=your_name AGE=your_AGE TEL=your_tel -f makefile
```

Comment: I thought the same and posted almost the same answer, but deleted it, because it's not what the OP wants. @indra wants to avoid using `var_name=var_value` but use `var_value` directly.

Comment: @KirilKirov: OP needs to use argument in random order. so in common sense, it is impossible to use without descriptor.

Comment: This soln may help , is it possible to check whether user has mentioned in the make file argument ,, ?  .. like I want to just check $make ENABLE_NAME  ENABLE_AGE etc ..